# Getting ADX value from outputted Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making this bot in which I need to get an ADX indicator which I get using this Library: https://github.com/anandanand84/technicalindicators/blob/master/test/directionalmovement/ADX.js

The code looks like this:

```
function updateIndicators(pair, price){
  var output = {};
  pairs[pair]['maValue'] = pairs[pair]['ma'].nextValue(price[2]);
  pairs[pair]['adxValue'] = pairs[pair]['adx'].nextValue({close: price[2] , high: price[3],
    low: price[4]});

  output = pairs[pair]['adxValue'];
  console.log(output);

  findTradeOpportunity(pair, price[2]);
  pairs[pair]['prevMaValue'] = pairs[pair]['maValue']
  pairs[pair]['prevClose'] = price[2];
}
```

And the variable pairs is defined like so:

```
  for(pair of pairsArray){
    pairs[pair]={
      ma: new SMA({period : maPeriods, values :[]}),
      maValue: 0,
      prevMaValue: 0,
      prevClose: 0,
      adx: new ADX({period: adxPeriods, close:[], high:[], low:[]}),
      adxValue: {},
      long: false,
      short: false,
      stopLossPrice: 0,
      entryAmount: 0,
      entryPrice: 0
    }
  }
```

The question is, when I log that output, that the nextValue object gives me according to the library I am using I get this:

```
{ adx: 34.906756996039285,
  pdi: 19.8213833578075,
  mdi: 36.373822501854036 }
```

And that is perfect. But I want to get only the adx value and I don't know how.
I tried doing:

```
console.log(output.adx)
```

But it doesn`t understands it, it gives me this in the terminal:

```
/home/jturolla/Documents/btcbot/manager.js:73
  console.log(output.adx);
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'adx' of undefined
    at updateIndicators (/home/jturolla/Documents/btcbot/manager.js:73:22)
    at Manager.runBot (/home/jturolla/Documents/btcbot/manager.js:54:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jturolla/Documents/btcbot/app.js:4:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

Need some help accessing this adx value. Thank you.
PS: Also tried JSON.parse() and no luck.

Comment: *"But it doesn`t understands it."* What exactly does that mean? Computers generally don't understand anything.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: You cannot get that log output for `console.log(output)` *and* get that error for the same value. Because either `output` is an object, or it is `undefined`. It cannot be both. Are you calling the function multiple times by any chance? We cannot really help you since we cannot run the code. The error is pretty obvious. Only you can really figure out why `nextValue` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, that is it. Like, I am running the function multiple times. And the first times I run it, the nextValue still doesnt have enought information to generate that output that I showed you. So in the first times it returns undefined. I can post the whole code if you`d like

Comment: So you either have account for that, i.e. code defensively and only do something with the value if it is not `undefined` or fix your implementation somehow so that it does not return `undefined`. Since that solution is specific to the library you are using, you either have to figure this out on your own or hope that somebody else is familiar with it.

Comment: Actualy, you just solved my problem. I am going to post the solution here in just a moment. Thank you verry much. I had to check if it was undefined before logging it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was indeed get the ADX result using

```
console.log(output.adx)
```

But checking first if it was not undefined, so the function looks like this now:

```
function updateIndicators(pair, price){
  var output = {};
  pairs[pair]['maValue'] = pairs[pair]['ma'].nextValue(price[2]);
  pairs[pair]['adxValue'] = pairs[pair]['adx'].nextValue({close: price[2] , high: price[3],
    low: price[4]});

  output = pairs[pair]['adxValue'];
  if(output){
    console.log(output.adx)
    findTradeOpportunity(pair, price[2]);
  }


  pairs[pair]['prevMaValue'] = pairs[pair]['maValue']
  pairs[pair]['prevClose'] = price[2];
}
```